# Connect batteries with different voltage in series

Tags: batteries

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB58GK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have two 9V batteries connected together in series. I also have a battery connected in parallel with total voltage of 6V and 700mah. I now want to connect the two sets of battery together in series. Is it safe to do this?

Bat3, Bat4, Bat5, Bat6, Bat7 is the second set. I want to make a total voltage of 24 voltage that is why I want to connect this two sets of battery.

Comment: This is not advisable! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there a way to connect two different voltage of batteries?

Comment: That makes it clearer now how it's connected, but the batteries in parallel will only be 1.2V for a total of 19.2V. You'd want them all in series for 24V but whether that's a good idea depends on the battery types and what current you want to draw.

Comment: Can you give citation? Because someone said the opposite.

Comment: @LorenzKyle, I don't have a citation but you can just try it both ways with a multimeter, with the uA type current draw a meter will have while measuring voltage you won't damage anything.

Comment: I tried it and it says 24V maybe the second set of batteries is series and I did the circuit wrong

Answer (score 9):

Mixing different batteries, whether in parallel or in series, is a bad idea.  Even enough of the same type of battery wired together is a bad idea.

Batteries are complicated electro-chemical devices.  They vary quite a bit with temperature, age, state of charge, discharge rate, and what your dog had for breakfast.  There is enough variation between "identical" batteries coming off the same assembly line that you have to be careful in combining them.  With different batteries, the answer is simply "don't do that".

With primary cells, there is more forgiveness since they are used once until dead, and therefore future ability to be rechargeable and hold a predictable amount of energy is irrelevant.  As such, it is allowable to let primary cells possibly suffer some damage as you try to get the last bit of energy from them.  However, if you go too far, they could rupture and cause physical damage to whatever equipment they are contained in.

Rechargeable cells have to be treated much more carefully.  Even just putting 4 cells, for example, in series is not so simple.  One cell will inevitably have lower capacity than the others.  This cell could be discharged so far as to cause damage, even when the stack voltage looks OK (the *average* cell voltage is above the damage limit).

Charging has the same issue.  The lowest capacity cell can be overcharged and damaged before the highest capacity cell is really full.

Properly designed systems with multiple rechargeable cells in series will have monitoring of individual cells, and usually some kind of "charge balancing" circuitry.  This shunts some of the charge current around the higher voltage cells to let the lower voltage cells catch up.  On discharge, the current is stopped as soon as the lowest cell gets to the point where continuing would cause damage.

To make things more tricky, there isn't a hard line between damage and no damage.  There are gray areas where deeper discharge or higher charge starts to decrease lifetime of the cell.  That lifetime is itself really a probability.

It gets complicated, and proper multi-cell battery management is a deep topic and will get significant design attention in real professional systems intended for a long life.

### Added in response to comment

The kanine nurishment dependency can have particularly tricky influence on performance, so has attracted much research.  According to a study commissioned by the Project for Object Oriented Paradigms and performed at the Boise Institute for Technical Excellence, this complex relationship can be distilled down to one simple to understand graph:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a chart showing dog food types and corresponding cell variation? :)

Comment: @JYelton: See addition to my answer.

Comment: This is awesome. Not only it is a useful guide, but it also serves as proof that electrical engineers can indeed have a sense of humor. :)